# Неправильное отображение оставшегося времни PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно, чтобы человек нажимая на кнопку получения бонуса смог ровно через сутки снова получить бонус.

Проблема в том, что когда человек нажимает на кнопку получения бонуса спустя час, то в ответ получает не "получение будет позможно через 23 часа", а наоборот, через 25 часов.

Код:

```
 if(DB::uCountColumns("SELECT * FROM `Bonus` WHERE `chat_id` = '$chatId' AND `date` >= NOW() -  INTERVAL '1' DAY")){
$hour = DB::uFetch("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR , `date`, NOW() + INTERVAL '24' HOUR) AS hour FROM `Bonus` WHERE `chat_id` = '$chatId' AND `date` + INTERVAL '24' HOUR > NOW()")["hour"];
  $welcomeMsg = "Следующий бонус будет доступен через *{$hour}* часа";
```

Что тут не так?

Comment: Ну все логично. у вас дата в прошлом. предположим она на час меньше чем сейчас, вы ее вычитаете из текущей даты +24 часа, а это как раз эти 24 часа плюс разница между текущим временем и датой вот и получилось 25 часов. вам надо к дате прибавить 24 часа и вычитать из этого текущую дату

Comment: То есть, замена делается в этой строке: `chat_id` = '$chatId' AND `date` + INTERVAL '24' HOUR > NOW()")["hour"];   ??

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался!